# Is possible to pass variables from premiere to after effect compositions?

Tags: premiere, after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

One of the latest features put inside AE & PR 2017 is the Live Text Edits..

In short you can mark an after effect composition as template and then all the texts inside that composition will be exposed in after effects as editable text.

Instead there's a way to expose some selected after effects composition variables directly to premiere with things like sliders and such ?

Would be cool prepare some comps and handle the things from premiere directly and see what changes..

I can think of some workaround for this but I wonder if this can be done directly!

Comment: Without actually trying it I can see a way you could do this. Make some text boxes that are hidden, and in AE use the source text values to drive expressions on other properties. This might work, but it would have the problem that the values of text boxes don't interpolate between frames, so you couldn't use them very well for animating properties.

Comment: @stib that was the same workaround that I was talking about in the question ^^